# Unable to clone or push to BPM 6.1.5, is anyone else having this issue?

Tags: git, jboss, jbpm, jboss6.x, business-process-management

I am running BPM 6.1.5 and am unable to clone or commit to the BPM server.  I running authenticating through active directory for BPM.  The client is getting this message : Invalid credentials.fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.  I am trying to clone and push through JBDS 8.

When I clone a repository from business-central using ssh this is the ERROR that appears in the server.log.

16:08:38,812 ERROR [org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl] (http-server/10.10.10.10:8443-4) Error during create repository: java.lang.RuntimeException: ssh://username@10.10.10.10:8001: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity of host '10.10.10.10' can't be established.

DSA key fingerprint is c1:3d:00:f2:ef:b3:05:0f:ca:b2:b0:c6:a1:52:62:7f.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting?

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.newRepository(GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.java:95) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.newRepository(GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.java:62) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryFactoryHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.newRepository(GitRepositoryFactoryHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryFactoryImpl.newRepository(RepositoryFactoryImpl.java:45) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryFactoryImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.newRepository(RepositoryFactoryImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl.createRepository(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:210) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl.createRepository(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:195) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl.createRepository(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:153) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.createRepository(RepositoryServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.AbstractRPCMethodCallback.invokeMethodFromMessage(AbstractRPCMethodCallback.java:48) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.callback(ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.java:22) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.RemoteServiceCallback.callback(RemoteServiceCallback.java:54) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints$2.callback(CDIExtensionPoints.java:396) [errai-weld-integration-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.DeliveryPlan.deliver(DeliveryPlan.java:47) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl.sendGlobal(ServerMessageBusImpl.java:293) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.SimpleDispatcher.dispatchGlobal(SimpleDispatcher.java:46) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:97) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:114) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet.doPost(DefaultBlockingServlet.java:142) [errai-bus-3.0.6.Final-redhat-2.jar:3.0.6.Final-redhat-2]

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecureHeadersFilter.java:53) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SecurityIntegrationFilter.java:45) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]

    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://username@10.10.10.10:8001: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity of host '10.10.10.10' can't be established.

DSA key fingerprint is c1:3d:00:f2:ef:b3:05:0f:ca:b2:b0:c6:a1:52:62:7f.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting?

    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.JGitUtil.cloneRepository(JGitUtil.java:220) [uberfire-nio2-jgit-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:594) [uberfire-nio2-jgit-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117) [uberfire-nio2-api-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83) [uberfire-nio2-api-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:225) [uberfire-io-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IOServiceIndexedImpl.newFileSystem(IOServiceIndexedImpl.java:197) [uberfire-metadata-commons-io-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    at org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.newRepository(GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.java:87) [guvnor-structure-backend-6.2.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:6.2.0.Final-redhat-14]

    ... 47 more

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://username@10.10.10.10:8001: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity of host '10.10.10.10' can't be established.

DSA key fingerprint is c1:3d:00:f2:ef:b3:05:0f:ca:b2:b0:c6:a1:52:62:7f.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting?

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.get(UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.java:118) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProviderUserInfo.promptYesNo(CredentialsProviderUserInfo.java:124) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:774) [jsch-0.1.50.jar:]

    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342) [jsch-0.1.50.jar:]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:248) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1111) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.3.2.201404171909-r.jar:3.3.2.201404171909-r]

    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.JGitUtil.cloneRepository(JGitUtil.java:199) [uberfire-nio2-jgit-0.5.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:0.5.8.Final-redhat-1]

    ... 53 more

Answer (score 0):

apparently it is missing entry in the known_hosts file.

You can try (with Eclipse, similar JBDS)

1. open perspective Git Repositories
2. Create new Repo. Ref: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Adding_a_Remote_Configuration
3. copy the URI SSH provided by the BPM Suite
4. Eclipse should ask whether you trust the RSA Key (yes)
5. try Dry-Run

Comment: Here is the ERROR that is appearing in the eclipse MARS 2 log. <div> Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: ssh://user.name@10.10.10.10:8001/testrepo0224: Invalid credentials.
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.cleanNotFound(TransportGitSsh.java:208)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:288)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:202)
 ... 4 more </div>

Comment: JBoss BPMS 6 does not allow push over https.